# cocos2d v3 collision detection

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, collision

I'm trying to inspect collision collision of two bodies, but collision detection callbacks are not being fired.
Here is my code:

1) My CCScene implements CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate protocol

2) I set collision delegate for physics

```
_physics = [CCPhysicsNode node];
_physics.gravity = PHYSICS_GRAVITY;
_physics.debugDraw = YES;
_physics.collisionDelegate = self;
[self addChild:_physics];
```

3) For each of two body I set a collision type

```
body1.collisionType       = @"body1";
body2.collisionType       = @"body2";
```

4) That's it, when these two bodies collide none of CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate callback methods is being called.

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA     typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
    return YES;
}
```

Could you please help me with this? Have you been able to receive collision callbacks in cocos2d v3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your callback methods?

Comment: - (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
    return YES;
}

Comment: I've tried new cocos2d template project, so I basically set _physics.collisionDelegate = self; but anyway callbacks are not fired

Comment: not sure but aren't collision types meant to group objects together that can collide? If so, then using two different types means they will not be able to collide

Comment: With the same collision type it doesn't work neither. Anyway, the bodies are colliding, the problem is that callback is not being fired. It's really weird..

Answer (score 3):

In cocos2d v3 physics, `collisionType` eliminates the need to set integer bit masks to define the type of collision. The parameter name `CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate` methods must be the collisionTypes that you want to deal with yourself. So in your case , the collision callback method should be

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair body1:(CCNode *)nodeA     body2:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    NSLog(@"HELLO");
    return YES;
}
```

By default everything collides in cocos2d, but if you set the `collisionGroup` of two bodies to be the same then they wouldn't collide.

Comment: Thanks very much, it works!! Other question is: is it possible to make two bodies not collide with each other but to be able to get callbacks when they intersect?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. I just return NO from ccPhysicsCollisionBegin

Comment: Yea I had trouble with same problem, and vola.. didn't notice that I needed to catch signature of callback method :|