# why collision not working , cocos2d v3?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

i create simple game like flapy bird with cocos2d v3 . 
Interface class:

```
@interface GameScene : CCScene<CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate>

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

+ (GameScene *)scene;
- (id)init;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
@end
```

In .m file:

```
          _physicsWorld =[CCPhysicsNode node];
          _physicsWorld.gravity=ccp(0, 0);
          _physicsWorld.collisionDelegate=self;
          _physicsWorld.debugDraw =YES;
          [self addChild:_physicsWorld];
          .........
          bird.physicsBody=[CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero,bird.contentSize} cornerRadius:0];
          bird.physicsBody.collisionGroup=@"birdGroup";
          bird.physicsBody.collisionType=@"birdCollision";
           [_physicsWorld addChild:bird];
          ........

    tubeBody.physicsBody.collisionGroup =@"tubeGroup";
    tubeBody.physicsBody.collisionType=@"tubeCollision";
    tubeBody.physicsBody.type=CCPhysicsBodyTypeStatic;

    [_physicsWorld addChild:tubeBody];
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB{
    [self endGame];
    NSLog(@"end game");
    return YES;
}
```

why method ccPhysicsCollisionBegin never call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680338/cocos2d-v3-collision-detection/22684444#22684444

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB{
```

To:

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair tubeCollision:(CCNode *)nodeA birdCollision:(CCNode *)nodeB{
```

You have the example code of the collision delegate, so you have to adapt it to your code with your nodeA that is the tube and nodeB the bird.