# Why is collision detection no longer working in cocos2d v3?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-3

In old project i create collisions like in this question:  [why collision not working , cocos2d v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555715/why-collision-not-working-cocos2d-v3/23560185#23560185) .
It ran ok, however when I created a new project something was wrong.
I don't know what I did differently this time. Please help me.

```
-(void)addAIAction:(int)i{
    if (!arrAI) {
        arrAI = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"res/gu_button.png"];
    sprite.position = [GameConfig convertPoint:ccp(viewSize.width, 160)];
    sprite.physicsBody.collisionType=@"aiCollision";
    sprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.contentSize.width/2 andCenter:ccp(sprite.contentSize.width/2, sprite.contentSize.height/2)];
    sprite.physicsBody.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;
    [_physicsNode addChild:sprite];
    [arrAI addObject:sprite];
}
```

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

```
-(void)update:(CCTime)delta{
    for (CCSprite *sp in arrPlayer) {
        sp.position= ccp(sp.position.x+playerSpeed, sp.position.y);
    }
    for (CCSprite *sp in arrAI) {
        sp.position= ccp(sp.position.x-aiSpeed, sp.position.y);
    }
```

implement delegate :

```
-(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair  playerCollision:(CCNode *)nodeA aiCollision:(CCNode *)nodeB{
    NSLog(@"Coll.");


- (id)init
{
    // Apple recommend assigning self with supers return value
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) return(nil);

    viewSize=CGSizeMake([GameConfig converPoint:480], [GameConfig converPoint:320]);
    _physicsNode = [CCPhysicsNode node];
    _physicsNode.collisionDelegate =self;
    _physicsNode.debugDraw =YES;
    _physicsNode.gravity=ccp(0, 0);
```

please let me know why " ccPhysicsCollisionBegin " never call
thanks everyone

Comment: "something wrong" means what exactly? what do you expect to happen, what happens instead?

Comment: method -(BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin nevercall, how i fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given no evidence to say your setting the delegate for the physics body, so therefore the ccPhysicsCollisionBegin method may not be called.

I don't know V3, but I'm guessing your going to need to add:

```
sprite.phisicsBody.deligate = self;
```

before you call `[_physicsNode addChild:sprite];` in your `addAIAction:`.