# CCPhysicsBody Collision not working in cocos2d-swift v3.4

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Here is code:

```
@interface MainScene : CCNode<CCPhysicsCollisionDelegate>
```

//.m

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];

    mPhysicsWorld = [CCPhysicsNode node];
    mPhysicsWorld.gravity = ccp(0,0);

    mPhysicsWorld.debugDraw = YES;
    mPhysicsWorld.collisionDelegate = self;

    [self addChild:mPhysicsWorld];

    //Body_A
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"sprite_1.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(280, 220);
        sprite.rotation = 13;
        sprite.name = @"Body_A";
        sprite.physicsBody.collisionGroup=@"Group1";
        sprite.physicsBody.collisionType=@"typeA";
        CGRect rect = {CGPointZero, sprite.contentSize};
        CCPhysicsBody *body = sprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:rect cornerRadius:0.0];
        body.velocity = ccp(1000, 2000);
        body.angularVelocity = 1.0;
        body.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;

        [mPhysicsWorld addChild:sprite];
    }

    //Body_B
    {
        CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"sprite_2.png"];
        sprite.position = ccp(380, 220);
        sprite.rotation = 13;
        sprite.name = @"Body_B";
        sprite.physicsBody.collisionGroup=@"Group2";
        sprite.physicsBody.collisionType=@"typeB";
        CGSize size = sprite.contentSize;
        CGPoint points[] = {
            ccp(0, 0),
            ccp(size.width, 0),
            ccp(size.width/2, size.height),
        };

        CCPhysicsBody *body = sprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithPolygonFromPoints:points count:3 cornerRadius:0.0];
        body.velocity = ccp(1000, -1000);
        body.angularVelocity = -1.0;
        body.type = CCPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic;

        [mPhysicsWorld addChild:sprite];
    }
```

//Delegate method

```
- (BOOL)ccPhysicsCollisionBegin:(CCPhysicsCollisionPair *)pair typeA:(CCNode *)nodeA typeB:(CCNode *)nodeB
{
    printf("Function Called\n"); //control not coming here
    if([nodeA.name isEqualToString:@"Body_A"] &&  [nodeB.name isEqualToString:@"Body_B"])
    {
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Similar Question: Already tried [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555715/why-collision-not-working-cocos2d-v3) but didn't get solution.

Comment: Not certain, but i think that this topic may have some bearing on your question: http://forum.cocos2d-spritebuilder.org/t/solved-collision-detection-issue/16839

Comment: I tried it in init method but nothing displayed.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg, here is code: https://app.box.com/s/c5csoh5bbmnfc8zx34jsngzx42gsh13n

Comment: if you don't mind check code in free time and give me answer..I can offer bounty. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are probably going to 'palm-forehead' , took me a while too :(

For both body A and body B the two lines below

```
sprite.physicsBody.collisionGroup=@"Group1";
sprite.physicsBody.collisionType=@"typeA";
```

are executed while physicsBody is still nil. Move the lines under the line :

```
CCPhysicsBody *body = sprite.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:rect cornerRadius:0.0];
```

ob cit. tested and verified, works on sim and device. Good luck with your project.

Comment: :- Sorry for simple mistake. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @DustBin removed comment. somehow i was able to infer the lineage :) ... but i cant remember exactly how (probably an url). You should remove your comment too then.